# Suddenly phone is dead for no reason (it has non-removable battery)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, micromax

We have a Micromax Q380 at home which is running Lollipop. It was working fine last night and suddenly it is not  responding this morning. Power button and it's combination with volume buttons won't work. It just looks like a dead phone. Display doesn't light up at all, even when charging. It's battery is non-removable which is the sad part of the story. What can I try before handing it over to a service store?

Comment: I assume you've tried charging it for hours?

Comment: Absolutely no! Overnight charging was not done.

Comment: Ok. Try to check if it's online for me: plug it into a computer and see if it shows up, or if you have Android Device Manager see if you can locate your phone from your computer. Or maybe try calling the phone? If you have a bluetooth smartwatch/speaker/keyboard will that connect?

Comment: Negative for all the questions. It is not responding for any of these.

Comment: So your battery is dead. Maybe your cable, power adapter, or wall outlet is broken? Can you try using a different cable with a different power adapter brick connected to a different wall outlet?

Comment: Battery got completely drained that even the display doesn't turn up on charging. Phone is up and running after hours of charging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Battery got so drained that the display doesn't turn up even when charging it. There was no problem with the mobile at all. My bad. Now it is up and running after hours of charging. I am not deleting this silly question because somebody might face similar silly issues in the future. Ain't they? ;-)